# Numbering are not showing on the side of header.php codes area

Tags: php, themes, visual-web-developer, datastax-astra, webdev.webserver

in my wordpress website astra theme header.php side numbering is not showing and code are also not colored. they are just like simple words

I tried to purge cache and then I pasted all codes again but, the problem is still there.